# Debian libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 undefined symbol hb_glib_script_from_script

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, authentication, wayland

I was installing some common packages I used everyday, like i3wm, jq, bat-musl, kitty, and so on, in a mostly fresh recent Debian. Then, when I tried to run a i3-msg command, I received the following error:

```
i3-msg: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: hb_glib_script_from_script
```

Then, suddenly, i3 wasn’t responding anymore and I had to force a reboot on the system. After that, the computer does not show the logon GUI screen anymore. Instead, it keeps showing me a black screen with a blinking underscore cursor like an empty tty forever. I can switch to another tty (like tty2 or 3) and login in a terminal environment. However, if I try to go back to tty1 where the login should appear, I get the black screen back and sometimes the system even won’t allow to change tty again, getting stuck in that black screen but with the cursor not blinking anymore. Although, even when it freezes like that, it responds to a single power off button click as a normal shutdown event (not forced).

After digging a lot, I tried to run gnome-shell by hand with the following command, but I always get the same error from the beginning with i3:

```
> dbus-run-session —- gnome-shell —-display-server —-wayland
gnome-shell: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: hb_glib_script_from_script
```

The library has the symbol required:

```
> nn -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 | grep glib
         U hb_glib_script_from_script
         U hb_glib_script_to_script
```

I already tried to reinstall the library, but the error doesn’t change. I am out of ideas of how to fix it and if this error is really the reason of why the login GUI screen is not showing up.

I do not want to reinstall the entire system. Does anyone can help me with it?

Here is my system version:

```
> uname-a
Linux pc-name 4.19.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2+dev10u1 (2020-06-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
         U hb_glib_script_from_script
         U hb_glib_script_to_script
```

doesn’t mean that the library *has* the symbol, it means the library *needs* the symbol; the `U` stands for “undefined”. (Strictly speaking, the library has the symbol, but no corresponding object.)

Try reinstalling `libharfbuzz0b`, which is the library implementing the symbol:

```
 sudo apt install --reinstall libharfbuzz0b
```

and make sure you don’t have any other version of `libharfbuzz` libraries, *e.g.* in `/usr/local/lib`.